# C++ function accepting any callable of a given templated signature

Tags: c++, c++14

If I understand it correctly, the standard way to write a function that accepts any callable as a parameter is:

```
template<typename Fn> void myFunction(Fn&& f) { ... }
```

I would like to do something similar, except I want to be able make `Fn` conform to a certain signature and I need to know the type of its parameter. For instance, something like:

```
template<typename T> void myFunction(std::function<void (T)>&& f) { ... }
```

The problem is this can't accept `packaged_task` or lambdas that capture move-only types like `std::promise`.

---

Update: Added an sample use case

Consider a simplified network request function:

```
template<typename T> void get(const Url& url,
                              const UrlQuery& params,
                              std::function<void (T)>&& callback) {
    auto response = doGet(url, query);
    callback(fromJson<T>(response));
}
```

This works reasonably well most of the time, but when I try to pass it a lambda that captures a `std::promise` it fails. I could use some workarounds to make that work, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way. Something closer to this pseudo code:

```
template<typename Fn<T>>
void get(const Url& url,
         const UrlQuery& params,
         Fn<T>&& callback) {
    auto response = doGet(url, query);
    callback(fromJson<T>(response));
}
```

Obviously that doesn't compile, but it sort of shows what I'd like.

To se the `T` parameter in the body of `get` while also keeping the `Fn&&` style parameter (eg. not specifying `std::function` or `std::packaged_task` as the type for `callback`) and also not needing to jump through any hoops when calling `get`.

Comment: Use `enable_if`?

Comment: Whats the signature you want?

Comment: The signature I want is like the second example: `void (T)` where T is a template parameter.

Comment: You want to deduce the `T` or you want to deduce the function type and require a given `T`? The former isn't generally possible - what would you want `myFunction([](auto ){})` to do?

Comment: Providing `T` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following, addressing the non-copyable-lambda part, works with MinGW g++ 7.2 and Visual C++ 2017:

```
#include <functional>       // std::function
#include <memory>           // std::shared_ptr
#include <utility>          // std::move

template< class Type >
void foo( std::function<void (Type)>&& f )
{
    f( 42 );
}

struct No_copy
{
    No_copy( No_copy const& ) = delete;
    auto operator=( No_copy const& ) -> No_copy& = delete;

    No_copy() {}
    No_copy( No_copy&& ) {}
    auto operator=( No_copy&& ) -> No_copy& { return *this; }
};

template< class Type >
class Copyable
{
    std::shared_ptr<Type> pf_;

public:
    template< class... Args >
    auto operator()( Args&&... args )
    { return (*pf_)( std::forward<Args>( args )... ); }

    Copyable( Type&& o )
        : pf_{ std::make_shared<Type>( std::move( o ) ) }
    {}
};

// Necessary for Visual C++ 2017:
template< class Type >
auto copyable( Type&& o ) { return Copyable<Type>{ std::move( o ) }; }

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main()
    -> int
{
No_copy o;
#ifdef DETAILED
    auto lambda = [oh{move(o)}]( int x ){ cout << x << " " << &oh << endl; };
    auto const c = copyable( move( lambda ) );
    foo<int>( c );
#else
    foo<int>( copyable( [oh{move(o)}]( int x ){ cout << x << " " << &oh << endl; } ) );
#endif
}
```

I haven't tried the particular types you mention, though.

Also, this code does not address the issue of deducing the argument type, if you want that (you'll have to add such deduction, if desired).

And, uhm, there's the issue of possible reference return type, not addressed here either.

:)